# AsciidoctorJ with explicity jruby dependency results in IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: grails, jruby

I followed some helpful advice (https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj/issues/313#issuecomment-119372587) to get asciidoctorJ working in my development environment by adding an explicity dependency on jruby:

```
compile 'org.jruby:jruby:9.0.0.0.rc1'
compile 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj:1.5.2'
```

However, when I pushed the code to our QA environment I now get the following message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.FieldVisitor, but class was expected
    at org.jruby.java.codegen.RealClassGenerator.defineOldStyleImplClass(RealClassGenerator.java:104)
    at org.jruby.java.codegen.RealClassGenerator.createOldStyleImplClass(RealClassGenerator.java:63)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.newInterfaceImpl(Java.java:1183)
    at org.jruby.java.proxies.JavaInterfaceTemplate.jcreateProxy(JavaInterfaceTemplate.java:281)
    at org.jruby.java.proxies.JavaInterfaceTemplate.access$000(JavaInterfaceTemplate.java:30)
    at org.jruby.java.proxies.JavaInterfaceTemplate$4.call(JavaInterfaceTemplate.java:181)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:661)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:198)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:624)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers.invoke(Helpers.java:500)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaUtil.convertProcToInterface(JavaUtil.java:248)
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.toJava(RubyBasicObject.java:800)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaEmbedUtils.rubyToJava(JavaEmbedUtils.java:273)
    at org.asciidoctor.internal.RubyUtils.rubyToJava(RubyUtils.java:18)
    at org.asciidoctor.internal.JRubyAsciidoctorModuleFactory.createAsciidoctorModule(JRubyAsciidoctorModuleFactory.java:27)
    at org.asciidoctor.internal.JRubyAsciidoctor.createJRubyAsciidoctorInstance(JRubyAsciidoctor.java:123)
    at org.asciidoctor.internal.JRubyAsciidoctor.create(JRubyAsciidoctor.java:62)
    at org.asciidoctor.Asciidoctor$Factory.create(Asciidoctor.java:647)
```

Based off research I belive I'm hitting ASM incompatibilities but I'm concerned that I don't have our codebase/dependencies isolated enough to get reproducible builds. I'd appreciate any advice on what steps I could take to ensure the build works across environments.

Answer (score 0):

Further research led me to discover that this was a (stupid) dependency issue between a Grails plugin and a jruby dependency. Grails was including asm-3.3.1 as a dependency of the grails-test-plugin. I tried setting export = false for the plugin but struggled to get that to work. My final solution was to add

`grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    delete {
        fileset(file: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.3.*.jar")
    }
}`

to our BuildConfig.groovy. That got us past the asm dependency conflict.